# CSRF Token not accepted (Spring)

Tags: spring, csrf

I run into a problem when adding CSRF to my existing and working CORS configuration.

Everytime a POST, PUT or DELETE is triggered I get the error that the current token I have is not the right one (nvalid CSRF Token 'edff86dc-093a-4df9-8218-e5343506bdf9' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.).

But when I compare them it can't be caused by the tokens. Also if i trigger a GET after that (e.g. PUT) the token before is sent again and accepted.

So I assume there might be a problem with my security config but I don't see what I'm missing.

security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/*/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/logout", "/admin/**").authenticated();
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/guestbook/**");
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
    http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

token filter:

```
public class CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
protected static final String REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "_csrf";
protected static final String RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME = "X-CSRF-HEADER";
protected static final String RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME = "X-CSRF-PARAM";
protected static final String RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, javax.servlet.FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    System.out.println(token.getToken());
    if (token != null) {
        response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME, token.getHeaderName());
        response.setHeader(RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME, token.getParameterName());
        response.setHeader(RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME , token.getToken());
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
  }
```

and for instance the cors filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");

    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "10");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-CSRF-TOKEN");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

    String headers = request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(headers )) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers );
    }

    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {

        try {
            response.getWriter().print("OK");
            response.getWriter().flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else{
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The problem **not only** occurs when I'm logged in. If i would not disable csrf on the  guestbook path there would also be no POST possible.

I hope anybody can give me a hint.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved my problem. After a lot of seach and error I discovered the  CsrfProtectionMatcher which can be used to enable CSRF on different paths.

Anyways this was very confusing to me, because I thought CSRF would be a always enabled on every request by default. So as soon as I applied the CsrfProtectionMatcher on my "/admin" path (allowing all possible methods, which is specified as null) it worked. [requireCsrfProtectionMatcher on docs.spring.io](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/CsrfConfigurer.html#requireCsrfProtectionMatcher%28org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher%29) , [detailed article](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2014/04/customizing-csrf-protection-in-spring-security/)

Also it's now possible for me, to work with a more simple configuration but despite that my old one works too.

old one with CsrfProtectionMatcher :

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    RequestMatcher csrfRequestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {

        private RegexRequestMatcher requestMatcher =
                new RegexRequestMatcher("/admin", null);

        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {

            if(requestMatcher.matches(request))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

    };      

    http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    http
    .csrf()
        .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher);
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/*/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/login", "/**/**/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/logout", "/admin/**").authenticated();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
    http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

more simple configuration:

```
http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    http
        .csrf()
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**/**")
            .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .permitAll();
    http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

I have to admit I still don't know why CSRF has to be explicit enabled. If anyone has an answer to that please tell me.